# Maintaining a list of SocketChannels that are unique

Tags: java, nio, hashcode, treemap, socketchannel

I am using Java NIO and selectors to get instances of `SocketChannel`s. I need to attach each instance of a SocketChannel that I get from the `selector` to an encryption key that is unique to each `SocketChannel` instance.

So I would like to keep a `TreeMap` where the key is the `SocketChannel` instance and then the value is the associated object to help with secure communications.

The problem is that the `SocketChannel` object is not `Comparable` (or whatever interface it needs to be to be a key) So I was using the SocketChannels `hashCode()` method to get a hash for that socket channel.

I've heard that the SocketChannel's hash is not necessarily unique, and in a system with many many connections, I fear that a hash collision can happen, and that the wrong client could be exchanging data with the server. My small fix was managing all these containers that contained a `SocketChannel` and a pointer to the next container, and to always check to see where the SocketChannel actually is the same object, but this leads to messy and ugly code.

Is there a better way to manage this situation?

Comment: Use a `HashMap`. `SocketChannel` doesn't have any inherent ordering, so there is no reason to expect a `TreeMap` to work, or to want it.

Comment: And this is what key attachments are for.